# react native ImageBackground not showing on IOS device

Tags: ios, image, react-native, react-native-image, imagebackground

I am using the ImageBackground component of react native, but in IOS (device) it is not displaying the image, in the simulator the image appears
What can this be?

code below:

```
import { ImageBackground } from 'react-native';

const imgSrc = require('../../assets/images/bg-login.png');

<ImageBackground
        resizeMode="cover"
        source={imgSrc}
        style={style.backgroundImage}
      >
```

style below:

```
backgroundImage: {
        width: screenWidth,
        height: '100%'
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add `asset` folder to your iOS build ?

Here the commande to do it :

```
react-native bundle --minify --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ./ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./ios
```

You will see asset folder and `main.jsbundle` file in the `ios` folder. After that go to `Xcode -> build phases -> copy bundle resources` and then add the `asset` folder and `main.jsbundle` file. Don't forget to click on the `Copy if needed`

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {


    return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <ImageBackground
            resizeMode="cover"
            source={require('../assets/oops.png')}
            style={{width:Dimensions.get('screen').width,height:Dimensions.get('screen').height}}
          >

      </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

try this code and use resizeMode as per your requirement